# Nested templates with dependent scope

Tags: c++, templates, scope, nested

What is dependent scope and what is the meaning of typename in the context of the following error?

```
$ make
g++ -std=gnu++0x main.cpp
main.cpp:18:10: error: need 'typename' before 'ptrModel<std::vector<Data> >::Type' because 'ptrModel<std::vector<Data> >' is a dependent scope
make: *** [all] Error 1


/*
 * main.cpp
 */

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct ptrModel
{
 typedef std::unique_ptr<T> Type;
};


template<typename Data>
struct ptrType
{
 typedef ptrModel< std::vector<Data> >::Type Type;
};

int main()
{
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The compiler told you exactly what to do. Write `typename` before `ptrModel<std::vector<Data> >::Type`, like so:

```
 typedef typename ptrModel<std::vector<Data> >::Type Type;
```

The *reason* for this requirement is that the compiler doesn't at this point know whether `ptrModel<std::vector<Data> >::Type` describes a member variable or a nested type. It can't even figure that out by looking at the definition of `ptrModel` because there might be a specialization of `ptrModel` for `std::vector<Data>` somewhere else in the program that it hasn't gotten to yet which changes which of these things `::Type` refers to. So you need to tell it explicitly.

The name `ptrModel<std::vector<Data> >::Type` has a "dependent scope" because it is in a scope that *depends* on the instantiation of a template.

Comment: Alright, but isn't it true it doesn't make sense to typedef a member variable?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't necessarily help due to some details about how templates are parsed by the compiler. See the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642229/why-do-i-need-to-use-typedef-typename-in-g-but-not-vs

Comment: I also found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6571836/24874) to be very helpful when coming across this error and concept for the first time.