# What's the correct syntax for a template class member fucntion to return a struct type?

Tags: stl

In [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file) one can learn how to store a template implementation in .cpp.  However I failed to do it if the return type is a struct which is defined inside the class.  See,

```
template<typename T>
class C1
{
public:
    struct s {
        int x;
    };

s GetS();

private:
s m_sInt;
};
```

in its .cpp, the below code will generate syntax errors.

```
template<typename T>
C1<T>::s C1<T>::GetS()
{
    return m_sInt;
}
```

Wonder what the right syntax should be in this case.

Comment: There is no object m_s in your class: there is only the object m_sInt

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
typename C1<T>::s C1<T>::GetS()
{
    return m_sInt;
}
```

The behaviour of compiler is explained in other questions about nested templates with dependent scope, e.g. [Nested templates with dependent scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311633/nested-templates-with-dependent-scope) or [Dependent scope and nested templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571381/dependent-scope-and-nested-templates/6571836#6571836)