# Variadic templates expansion recursively for classes and functions

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, visual-studio-2013

So I've been trying to understand variadic templates a little bit more,
My goal was to receive all types, expand them, and print them..
I was able to do it in for a function(found some examples) but I was not able to do it for a class
Here I am trying to build a 'Master' to hold many 'Slaves', each Slave is supposed to have a Slave_T inherit from him and then know it's type, and print it on c'tor.

But for some reason I am not able to fix the ambigious compilation error.. I was trying to avoid passing any of the type as parameters to the function.. I tried with enable_if or true/false_type convensions but was unable, anyone has any idea?
This is my code:(function expansion included)

Function expansion that works:

```
template<typename T, typename... Targs>
void Print(T value, Targs... Fargs) // recursive variadic function
{
    Print<T>();
    Print(Fargs...); // recursive call
}

template<typename T>
void Print(T = NULL)
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << endl;
}
```

Class Expansion that I need help with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;



struct Slave {
    virtual char const* Type() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Slave_T : public Slave{
    virtual char const* Type() {
        return typeid(T).name();
    }
};

template <typename ...T>
struct Master {
    Master()
    {
        MakeSlave<T...>();
        cout << "All Slaves:" << endl;
        for (auto const& slave : v){
            cout << slave ->Type() << endl;
        }
    }
private:

    template<typename T, typename ...Rest>
    void MakeSlave()
    {
        MakeSlave<Rest...>(); MakeSlave<T>();
    }

    template<typename T>
    void MakeSlave()                    {
        v.push_back(new Slave_T<T>());
    }

    vector<shared_ptr<Slave>> v;
};

int main()
{
    Master<int, double, char> m;
    //Print("Hello", '!', 123, 123);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Alon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First of all:** To allow polymorphic templates, you have defined a non-templated pure-virtual base class `Slave`. Your template class `Slave_T` must inherit from it (You want a `std::vector` containing heterogeneous templates, right?). And note that you are using the virtual function defined by the base class `Slave`. I think you have forgotten to write the base class list before `struct Slave_T` :)

**Second:**  In that override of the virtual function `Type()`, you have written `Slave<T>::type` instead of `Slave_T<T>::type`. Also note that this sentence needs `typename` keyword before it, because [is a reference to a dependent scope.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3311640/1609356). But, on the other hand, you have access to the `Slave_T` template param `T`, so, why you don't simply use `T`? :)

**Third:** Prefer to use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) instead of a raw `new` sentences.

**Fourth:** Prefer [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of C-style raw-strings.

### Edit after code fixes:

Template param `T` of private function `MakeSlave()` shadows the class variadic template param `T`. You must have to use other name.

By the way, the error is that in the overloads of makeslave are ambiguous: You have defined a version with template params `T` and variadic `Params`, that is, the tipicall *HEAD TAIL* recursive approach used with variadic packs. But, on the other hand, you also define a version with only one template param. Note that this make ambiguity with the first version, because a variadic pack can be empty, so in your base case the compiler donesn't know what version use.

### Solution:

You could use a sentinel type to track when the param list is completely processed. You use this sentinel to enable/disable the base case to avoid the ambiguity:

```
template <typename ...T>
    struct Master {
        Master()
        {
            MakeSlave<T...,_my_centinel_type>();
            cout << "All Slaves:" << endl;
            for (auto const& slave : v){
                cout << slave ->Type() << endl;
            }
        }
    private:
        struct _my_centinel_type {};

        template<typename U, typename ...Rest>
        typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U,_my_centinel_type>::value , void>::type MakeSlave()
        {
                v.push_back( std::make_shared<Slave_T<U>>());
                MakeSlave<Rest...>();
        }

        template<typename U>
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,_my_centinel_type>::value , void>::type MakeSlave(){
            //The base case does anything
        }
```

See it in action: http://ideone.com/FqMPXh#

Comment: That is all very true, yet it does not answer my question, I wasn't asking how to implement Slave & Slave_T, I was just doing some scribbles there, my question is how to compile it with the variadic tempaltes syntax, as it says it has ambiguity problems for the last iteration...

Comment: @Alon First fix the errors (Points one and two). Then we could solve your problem

Comment: @Alon and please, give me the compiler errors messages and where they be produced

Comment: Ok, fixed that at least(can't believe I forgot inheritence..), the compiler errors are easily reproduced (Copy it & try to compile), it would say amiguity calls at the MakeSlave<Rest...> call for the last iteration where Rest is one(or zero)

Comment: @Alon. Sorry. See the last edit. I fixed the code. Accept please