# Can a class be used as generic namespace (using templates)?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

I have a namespace with several functions I use with a class that was already defined

```
class Object {
    struct SubObject{
        //...
    };
    //...
};


namespace Process
{
    Object::SubObject function1(Object& o){
        //..        
    }

    void function2(Object& o){
        //..
    }
}
```

Now, I have to generalize those functions with a template, I've noticed I cannot use one template over an entire namespace. Either I have to make a template for each functions (rather tedious considering I have to typedef each struct of the class each time), or I would like to know if I can do something like defining a class instead of a namespace :

```
template<typename TObject>
class Process
{
    typedef typename TObject::SubObject TSubObject;

    TSubObject function1(TObject& o){
        //..        
    }

    void function2(TObject& o){
        //..
    }
}
```

Is that correct code ? It seems strange to make a class I will never instanciate.

Also, I first wrote :

```
typedef TObject::SubObject TSubObject;
```

But my compiler asked me to add typename in front of TObject, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311633/nested-templates-with-dependent-scope) explaining (or that's how I understood it) that it was because the compiler doesn't know if SubObject is a nested type or an member variable. But isn't typedef obligatorily followed by a type, then an alias ? 
I thought a class member (a variable or a function) cannot be "typedef"ed.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You can't call the functions in your sample without an instance, you'll need to make them `static` functions then! Another option is to simply provide templated functions at the namespace level.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : Yes but I would have to make a template for each functions in the namespace, and make a typedef for each nested type in each function (I have like a dozen of nested type in Object, I would like to avoid doing typedef/typename every time).

Comment: Then use the other option with static functions in a templated class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ grammar/specification states that any time there is a qualified name that may be a type or a variable (even in say a `typedef` context), it will always be considered as a variable unless you prefix it with `typename`.