# How can I make a function that takes either a map or an unordered_map?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm implementing some template-based serialization. I implemented the templated function for `std::map`, but now I'm using an `std::unordered_map`. I would rather not copy & paste the entire function and just change the parameter type. Is there any way to make a template which takes only a map or an unordered map?

Comment: Why such a restriction? What if someone wants to use your function with their own implementation of a map that has the same interface as `std::map`?

Comment: @Brian: That would be fine, but I think I am restricted by the serialization framework from defining a `serialize` function that takes any parameter. Wouldn't it clash with other `serialize` functions that say, take ints specifically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template <typename MAP>
void generic_foo(MAP& map)
{
    // generic implementation of your function
    // that works with unordered_map and map

    using K = typename MAP::key_type;
    using T = typename MAP::mapped_type;
}

// matches any possible implementation of std::unorderd_map
template <class Key,                                    
          class T,                                   
          class Hash,                       
          class Pred,                  
          class Alloc>
void foo(std::unordered_map<Key, T, Hash, Pred, Alloc>& m)
{
    // signature matched! forward to your implementation
    generic_foo(m);
}

// matches any possible implementation of std::map        
template <class Key,                                    
          class T,                          
          class Compare,                  
          class Alloc>
void foo(std::map<Key, T, Compare, Alloc>& m)
{
    // signature matched! forward to your implementation
    generic_foo(m);
}
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdfdb98f935dfc09)

Comment: But this is not what Paul Evans answered?

Comment: @TomásBadan It is, but it's got a fully-functional example. It's a more complete answer.

Comment: One issue: how can I access the key & value types from `generic_foo`? I need to get `pair`s out of the map

Comment: @PiotrS.: I mean the types, not the values. I can't do `std::pair<K, V> item;` since those types aren't in the template. I tried `MAP::value_type item;` but it says "need ‘typename’ before ‘Map:: value_type’ because ‘Map’ is a dependent scope"

Comment: @Claudiu Then add `typename`...`typename MAP::value_type item;`

Comment: @PiotrS.: Oh nice, didn't realize it was that simple ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311633/nested-templates-with-dependent-scope) helped explain it). Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Simply *overload* the function as a non-templated function with one overload to take an `std::map` and another to take an `std::unordered_map`.  Have these two functions call a hidden `template` that takes anything but can only be called by them.  One way to do this is to hide it in an anonymous `namespace`.

Comment: @PiotrS. This **doesn't** *copy & paste the entire function*! That is the function that is renamed, hidden and simply changed to take anything rather than use an `std::map`

Comment: *non-templated function that takes std::map* makes no use, since the types are hard-coded, whereas the OP's original function is a template. any mismatch with a type within map/unorderd_map will resolve the overload to the generic one

Comment: This was the right idea, and I upvoted, but Piotr helped take me to the final working implementation

Answer (score 2):

### With C++20 concepts

**To support specifically `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`:**

```
template<typename T> struct is_unordered_map
   : public std::false_type {};

template<typename... Args>
struct is_unordered_map<std::unordered_map<Args...>>
   : public std::true_type {};

template<typename T> struct is_map
   : public std::false_type {};

template<typename... Args>
struct is_map<std::map<Args...>>
   : public std::true_type {};

template<typename C>
concept UnorderedMap = is_unordered_map<C>::value;

template<typename C>
concept Map = is_map<C>::value;

template<typename C>
concept MappingContainer =
    Map<C> || UnorderedMap<C>;

void foo(const MappingContainer auto& m) { ... }
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/MrsaGn

---

**To support any type that behaves as a mapping type:**

```
template<typename C>
concept MappingContainer = requires(C c) {
    typename C::key_type;
    typename C::mapped_type;
    typename C::value_type;
    typename C::iterator;
    requires std::same_as<decltype(c.begin()), typename C::iterator>;
    requires std::same_as<decltype(c.end()), typename C::iterator>;
    requires std::same_as<
        typename C::value_type,
        std::iter_value_t<typename C::iterator>
    >;
    requires std::same_as<
        typename C::value_type,
        std::pair<const typename C::key_type, typename C::mapped_type>
    >;
};

void foo(const MappingContainer auto& m) { ... }
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/jPfMhT

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<type_traits>
template<typename T>
void foo(T t){
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, std::map</*some_type*/>::value
               || std::is_same<T, std::unordered_map</*some_type*/>::value,
                  "Foo can only get std::map or std::unordered_map.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that extracts keys/values from `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`

```
template <typename M>
std::unordered_set<typename M::key_type> GetMapKeys(const M& a_map) {
  std::unordered_set<typename M::key_type> keys;
  for (auto const& e : a_map) {
    keys.emplace(e.first);
  }
  return keys;
}

template <typename M>
std::vector<typename M::mapped_type> GetMapValues(const M& a_map) {
  std::vector<typename M::mapped_type> values;
  values.reserve(a_map.size());
  for (auto const& e : a_map) {
    values.push_back(e.second);
  }
  return values;
}
```