# How to make a static map<string, TNested> as member of template class?

Tags: c++, templates, static

The following code fails to compile with the following error:

> Error C2923   'std::map': 'Foo::CacheEntry' is not a valid
>   template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

Why is Foo::CacheEntry not a valid template type argument?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template<int arga>
class Foo {
private:
    class CacheEntry {
    public:
        int x;
    };
    static std::map<std::string, CacheEntry> cache;
};

template<int argb>
std::map<std::string, Foo<argb>::CacheEntry> Foo<argb>::cache = std::map<std::string, Foo<argb>::CacheEntry>();
```

Comment: `std::map<std::string, typename Foo<argb>::CacheEntry>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311633/nested-templates-with-dependent-scope - The error message of Visual Studio is not that straightforward though.

Answer (score 2):

`Foo<argb>::CacheEntry` is a dependent name, so you need to tell the compiler that it names a type with the `typename` keyword:

```
template<int argb>
std::map<std::string, typename Foo<argb>::CacheEntry> Foo<argb>::cache{};
```

Note that the copy-initialization is pretty redundant, you can just use value-initialization.

If you find yourself needing that type a fair amount, you can make an alias for it:

```
template<int arga>
class Foo {
private:
    class CacheEntry {
    public:
        int x;
    };
    using CacheMap = std::map<std::string, CacheEntry>;
    static CacheMap cache;
};

template<int argb>
typename Foo<argb>::CacheMap Foo<argb>::cache {};
```