# Cannot typedef iterator in a class inherited from std::vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I need to use typedef typename in g++ but not VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642229/why-do-i-need-to-use-typedef-typename-in-g-but-not-vs)

I am defining a template class as follows

```
template <class T>
class MyVector : public std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T>>
{
public:
   typedef MyVector::iterator MyIter;
};
```

I get this error at the typedef for `MyIter`

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I am compiling using VS 2010, I have made sure that the includes for `vector` and `boost::shared_ptr` are present. If I remove the template `T` and replace it with `int` everything compiles without error.

What am I missing? I want to define a template class and typedef the iterator.

Comment: Try putting `typename` between `typedef` and `MyVector`. See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: See arguments for & against public inheritance of `std::vector<>`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector

Comment: Also read the useful book "Exceptional C++" where this problem is well clarified

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is very well answered here:
[Why do I need to use typedef typename in g++ but not VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642229/why-do-i-need-to-use-typedef-typename-in-g-but-not-vs)

But long story short, you must use the keyword *typename* in this way:

```
typedef typename MyVector::iterator MyIter;
```

Because in the first pass (verifying template syntax) the compiler doesn't really know if *MyVector::iterator* is a type or a variable (what it is actually going to be on the specialized template). So hinting it that it is a type fixes the issue.