# Iterator for vector of pointers error expected ;

Tags: c++, templates, stl, vector, iterator

I am using a vector of pointers to create a data structure and find that I am getting an error that seems unclear. Here is the basic code from the header file

```
#include <vector>  
using namespace std;  
template <typename Key, typename Value>  
class ST{  
    class STNode{  
    public:  
        STNode(Key k, Value v) : key(k), value(v){}  
        ~STNode(){}  
        Key key;  
        Value value;  
    };  
typedef typename ST<Key, Value>::STNode Node;  
public:  
    ST():v(NULL) {v = new vector<Node*>();}  
    ~ST(){  
        // vector contains allocated objects  
        for(vector<Node*>::iterator it = v->begin(); it != v->end(); ++it)  
        delete (*it);  
        delete v;  
    }  
private:  
    vector<Node*>* v;  
};
```

The error message I am receiving on g++ version 4.6.6 is

```
ST.h: In destructor 'ST<Key, Value>::~ST()':  
ST.h:20: error: expected ';' before 'it'  
ST.h:20: error 'it' was not declared in this scope
```

I have tried removing the for loop and simply attempted to declare the iterator and get the scope error. My searches have shown that usually this is attributed to a missed semicolon at the end of the inner class or the lack of public being in the inner class, but this is not the case.  Is there a special declaration necessary for an iterator of a vector of pointers?

Comment: A member pointer to container is rarely useful.  Consider making the member `vector<Node*> v;` instead of `vector<Node*>* v;`.

Comment: @aschepler And more important: it's error-prone... Most people forget that an object can be copied... (Rule of Three)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suffering from an interesting quirk of the C++ language.  You need to add a `typename` to you declaration of the iterator (`typename vector<Node*>::iterator it`).  More infomation can be found in the question [Why do I need to use typedef typename in g++ but not VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642229/why-do-i-need-to-use-typedef-typename-in-g-but-not-vs)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I assumed the typename in the typedef would be sufficient. Informative link btw. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add typedef for `vector<Node*>::iterator` as it is a `dependent name` which depends on template a template parameter.

```
for(typename vector<Node*>::iterator it = v->begin(); it != v->end(); ++it)
```