# Cannot apply const to typedef reference

Tags: c++, constants, const-correctness

The following code works when applying `const` to a return value reference of `value_type&` but errors if I use a typedef of the same type.

As an example:

```
class T {
};

class A {
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef value_type& reference;

    // Not working
    const reference operator*() const;

    // But this works?
    //const value_type& operator*() const;
};

// Error!
const typename A::reference A::operator*() const {
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

g++ will error with:

```
'const' qualifiers cannot be applied
```

My actual code uses templates but I've removed for the example and substituted class `T` instead. This has no bearing on the error.

I don't see why this won't work if specifying `value_type&` instead compiles fine.

Comment: I didn't see any obvious errors and this compiles and runs fine for me in visual studio. I'll wait for someone more familiar with G++ answer this.

Comment: Although this seems to be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642229/why-do-i-need-to-use-typedef-typename-in-g-but-not-vs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two different issues here.

First, in:

```
typedef T* pointer;
typedef const pointer const_pointer;
```

the type of `const_pointer` is actually `T* const`, not `const T*`. The constness attaches to the pointer, not to the type pointed to.

Now references obey the same logic: if you make a typedef for the reference type, and try to attach `const` to it, it will try to apply the `const` to the reference type, not the referenced type. But references, unlike pointers, are not allowed to have top-level cv-qualification. If you try to mention `T& const`, it's a compilation error. But if you try to attach the cv-qualification through a typedef, it's just ignored.

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced
>   through the use of a *typedef-name* (7.1.3, 14.1) or *decltype-specifier *(7.1.6.2), in which case the cv-qualifiers
>   are ignored.

([dcl.ref]/1)

So the second issue is that GCC thinks this is an error, whereas the standard clearly states that it should not be an error, it should just ignore the `const`. I think this is a bug in GCC. Clang does not produce an error: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b5c105941066708

Comment: Upvoted for the standard quote. Didn't know that it is legal. There is an old (2008) discussion on comp.lang.c++.moderated about exactly this issue: http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.c++.moderated/const-reference-typedef-compile-error/257420 But couldn't find (yet) a gcc bug report.

Comment: Oddly enough, `const A::reference` works. Presumably the utterly pointless `typename` caused a different code path to be triggered.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot apply const to a reference, like const(ref(type)).

But you can have a reference to a const type, like ref(const(type)).